# Как мне убрать лишнее на java?

Tags: java

У меня есть переменная

```
public static double ezz = Serverexe.setmgr.getSettingByName("ArrayListSpeed").getValDouble();
```

которая возращяет `2239.0`, как мне убрать .0 в конце?

Comment: `getValInteger()` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не работает

Comment: а зачем убрать? Так - явно видно, что это вещественное число, а не какое-то там целое. Тем более, что влияние это оказывает только на строковое представление, а в представленном коде строкового представления и не видно...

Comment: Если задавать одинаковые вопросы, то рано или поздно забанят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `double` на `int`, а так же добавьте приведите к `int`

```
public static int ezz = (int)(Serverexe.setmgr.getSettingByName("ArrayListSpeed").getValDouble());
```